# LAMP - file doesn't appear under tmp directory

Tags: php, directory, tmp

I am uploading an image using an HTML form.

When I get the full path to the image, it outputs something like this:

`'/tmp/phpkIv1BY/10259944_770025219687938_1184503840380306483_n.jpg'`

but when I go to the `/tmp` folder, the sub-folder `phpkIv1BY` doesn't even exist! What's going on here?

Comment: Maybe it is just going to your machine's tmp folder

Comment: How do I find out where it is?

Comment: Try checking if /tmp or /var/tmp folders have the sub-folder mentioned.

Comment: They don't, I've already checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason for this behaviour**

All uploaded files are temporarily stored in the folder location as defined in

(In php.ini)

upload_tmp_dir =

(Read more about this: http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir)

These temporarily stored files are no longer exist after that php script execution(As mentioned in previous answer request life span) finished.

**Do the following to view uploaded file while script executing.**

> upload.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> upload_file.php

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
        $fp=fopen("/tmp/write.log","w+");
        fputs($fp,"Original Name:".$_FILES["file"]["name"].";temporay Name:".$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]."\n");
        fclose($fp);
        sleep(50000);
}
?>
```

Upload file by upload.html

In another terminal apply tail in /tmp/write.log after uploading image(Because sleep time is too much so you able to find the image)

*#tail -f /tmp/write.log*

Copy that temporary file into any place and place the extension of original image file

For example my printed log line is

Original Name:digits.png;temporay Name:/tmp/phpOKlpoK

(Needed to do this with root privilages)

*#cp /tmp/phpOKlpoK /home/sandeep/Desktop/file.png*

*#chown sandeep.sandeep /home/sandeep/Desktop/file.png*

So this is the uploaded file that you.

(
Instead of doing all these steps for checking uploaded images you can use move_uploaded_file()
)

Answer (score 0):

I can not find anywhere if PHP might create a temporary folder for temporary uploaded files. But what is certain is that uploaded files are kept temporary and as soon as the request is done, they are removed. So if you think you can find some uploaded file in the `/tmp` folder, think again.

If you would like some uploaded file to live longer than a request life span, then you need to move it somewhere safe using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Comment: Once the file is submitted using a form, I try to process it using the Intervention Image library by passing the tmp url to the `Image::make()` method, but it acts as if it can't handle the file. If I move the file to a folder and the pass it on to the library, it works. How do I make it work with the tmp file? I wish to do it because I want to process the file as image first, and only then move it to the upload folder (in case it's a potentially dangerous file).

Comment: What exactly you want to do with the intervention library ?